# WPF Datagrid dynamic columns from model property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Using WPF datagrid with MVVM structure (no code behind).  I was wondering if it was possible to take a model property that normally shows up in a single column and use that to dynamically generate new columns.

Example

```
public Class1
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public double Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Mock up standard datagrid

```
|Property1|Property2|Property3|
| 1       | A       | 1.25    |
| 2       | B       | 2       |
| 3       | B       | 3       |
```

Mock up desired datagrid

```
|Property1| A     | B   |
| 1       | 1.25  |     |
| 2       |       | 2   |
| 3       |       | 3   |
```

There is no limit on what value Property2 can be.

Comment: Yes thats possible. What you tried ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I would like to know how this should be possible without using any event (and maybe with less than 500 lines of code)

Comment: Using Linq you can `project` the given list into required list.

Comment: And work with anonymous objects? That's nonsence... As soon as he wants to use the data again he will have a big problem and a List<object>...

Comment: I can do this with code behind by using Linq with a group by on Property2 and adding columns to the datagrid in a foreach loop. In the loop I would have another linq query to add the values the in right spots, but I am looking for a no code behind solution.